# NGINX gaves 404 error after creating a symlink

Tags: laravel, nginx, server, phpmyadmin, symlink

My site runs on php-larvel and nginx as webserver and the root diectory is `/public` , everything was ok ,but when I wanted to secure my phpmyadmin login url , creating a symlink by this command in `/public_html :`

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin-YOUR-SECRET-CODE
```

site went down showing 404 , and the nginx shows this error:

> 2019/04/07 07:09:02 [error] 4163#4163: *110 directory index of
>   "/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/" is forbidden

the nginx configuration has already set to serve on `/public` . I don't know why it is trying to access public_html on requests .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user that NGINX is running as must be able to access the directories its attempting to read and/or write to. In most cases, NGINX is either running as the user nginx or www-data.

We can check for the user directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf by running:

grep user /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
If the return of that command spits out a user, we can then change the ownership of the directories you've mentioned using chown.

chown -R user:group /insert/path/here
So if NGINX is running as www-data:

chown -R www-data:www-data /insert/path/here
If the grep command doesn't spit out a user, we can always see who owns NGINX's directories and we should be able to use that user.

Simply run:

ls -al /etc/nginx
and grab the user from the output.

As a side note, things are a bit different if you happen to be running PHP-FPM with NGINX. In that case, the directories and files should be owned by the user that the PHP-FPM process is running as.

If you are running PHP-FPM, you can cd in to the main directory and check the pool file. If you've not modified anything there for your setup, the default user for PHP-FPM is always www-data, so that should be the user who owns all files and directories.

cd /etc/php/*/fpm/pool.d/
and then:

nano www.conf